# When does Angular add a directive template to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to use a Javascript library (scrollReveal) that assumes that the full DOM is ready. I am currently using AngularJS.

The problem is, I don't know when to initialize scrollReveal via

```
window.sr = new scrollReveal();
```

If I do this in the link function of one directive, it may not apply to the template of another directive, because the other template may not have been added to the DOM yet.

So I have two questions:

1) At what time is the directive template added to the DOM? Does it differ if I use template vs templateUrl?

2) How do I add in additional code that assumes a full DOM?

Thanks.

Comment: Template with having ng-repeat in it would have very different way to handle it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) At what time is the directive template added to the DOM? Does it differ if I use template vs templateUrl?**

You can use what you prefer.However, it is a much cleaner solution to write your html in a separate file. I personally prefer `templateUrl` because I think putting your html code into a string is not a good practice. But it has no difference when executing the code.

**2) How do I add in additional code that assumes a full DOM?**

$timeout is an Angular's wrapper for window.setTimeoutset. Timeout removes the function from the execution queue and it will only be invoked after JavaScript has finished with the current execution queue. So that is why your model will be updated before the excecution.

Here is an example:

```
$timeout(function(){
   // template should be visible now
[,optional delay]);
```

$timeout will not run until digest cycle completes.

Comment: 1)  This doesn't answer my question: when is the directive template added to the DOM? It's certainly sometime before the link function, but I haven't found a better way to reason about it. For example, if you have two directives with two templates, I don't know which template gets added first.


2) Using $timeout seems like a hack: you're saying just wait some number of seconds and hope that the DOM has been fully loaded by then?

Comment: $timeout is not waiting "some time" for hoping it is fully loaded. Angularjs renders the template after calling $digest, which is called first of your timeout code. When you use $timeout without a delay you are "queuing" that code at the end of the javascript's queue. That is why you can be sure that the DOM has already been updated